# Using a base dialect with pyodbc in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I can connect via pyODBC to an unsupported database over ODBC. Queries appear to execute correctly. If I try to connect using mssql+pyodbc, I can't connect properly (image not found).

I've tried "base:///", "base+pyodbc:///", or "pyodbc:///".

Do I need to write my own "dialect" that doesn't make any changes to base, and are there any useful (up to date) guides on how to do this?

EDIT:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN = "ODBCCONNECTIONNAME", UID = "ODBCUSER", PWD="PASSWORD")
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Also works with this line replacing the connection above:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=fmp_production;UID=odbc_user;PWD=Pwd222")
```

I can then run selects, and modifications fine, using standard SQL.

EDIT:

Okay, so I'm getting an error:
"Abort trap: 6" basically my python process is crashing out. I've tried testing with a functioning ODBC connection to a MySQL database, using:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pyodbc://root:rootpwd@testenvironment')
```

If I include the name of the database, then I get an image not found error instead. But I think the actual problem is whatever is crashing my python.

Comment: Please post the code (including the [connection string](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/dialects/mssql.html#dialect-mssql-pyodbc-url)) that you've tried. The code sample should demonstrate if you're `1)` using a DSN or inline connection attributes, `2)` connecting to a default or named SQL Server instance, and `3)` connecting with Windows integrated or SQL Server authentication.

Comment: I'm not using SQL server, I'm using an unsupported ODBC database. I'll post up the connection strings, but they work in pyodbc. I'm asking how you can connect using just pyODBC and the default base SQL dialect.

Comment: Got it, the `mssql+pyodbc` threw me off. The connection string that was successfully used with pyodbc may be helpful for others to provide input.